# MVC 4 : Show input field based on type user selects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, dynamicform

I probably have already asked similar question to this, but this one is little different.

I am at a point where user has an option to add a hardware in the system.
User can select its type while adding the Hardware, now based upon the type I can get its kind, and each Hardware kind its list of properties (some Hardware has one property, some two and some three or more).

The thing I haven't been able to figure out is how can I show input text boxes where the user can provide the properties based upon the type the user selects. I have to provide the name of the property based upon the type and user types the value. Which then I have to retrieve from view and save.

Here is a small image of what the hierarchy looks like.
[image]

Here is the image of what my current view looks like.
[image]

So, now whenever user types in ModuleID and selects the type, I need to be able to show some input text box or new form based upon the type where user can enter the property value.

Here is my view model, which I don't know is the right one or not for this situation.

```
public class CreateModule
    {
        [Required]
        public string ModuleId { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string SelectedModuleTypeName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TypeNames { get; set; }

        public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    }
public class Property
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Has anyone done something like this before, or have idea how to solve this problem? Any tips, idea, suggestions, useful links are welcome.

I hope I have explained my issue properly if not, do comment on how can i make it better.